# How can I beat an Eagle Artillery in clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am trying to beat an eagle artillery and every time I lose, I never get even one star. I need a suggestion how to beat an eagle artillery so that I can be in the legends league. Is there a spell to stop an Eagle Artillery? Maybe a unit that can take lots of damage? I need some suggestions, can you tell me how to beat that defense?

Answer (score 2):

Rushing that defense fast!

Golems will be swiftly destroyed so try to destroy the Eagle Artillery as fast as you can or use a hybrid attack (an attack that consists of multiple waves) as that defense will recalculate its targets after every volley. If necessary, bring Freeze Spells or take a chance and Lightning Spell and Earthquake Spell the Eagle Artillery to destruction.

As there is no recommended attack strategy yet, bring armies that target defenses, like Lavaloonion. Bring hastes and rage to help speed up the process. Lots of other tips can be seen [here](http://www.allclash.com/eagle-artillery-attacking-strategy/) such as:

- Spreading out your troops to prevent splash damage
- Using heroes as distractions
- Using Grand Warden's Ability of temporary invincibility
- Using strategies like BARCH, Giants + Goblins, GoWiWi, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm 1 month late :|

### My personal best strategy

Don't deploy more than `50%` of your army, deploying more that half activates the eagle artillery.

---

### BUT WAIT

If the artillery is upgrading, Outside or near Outside of the village, then you have a good chance of destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just attack the base that has the Eagle exposed near the outer walls... use a queen walk (queen and 4 healers) and king and warden for distraction.  It's only 75 hs for the heros and the total hs is less than 150 so the eagle won't even be activated.  Its easy to take out eagles when bases have them exposed.